# regex to remove doctype

Tags: c#, xml, regex, doctype

I am looking for a regex to strip the following doctype declarations from a set of xml documents:

```
<!DOCTYPE refentry [ <!ENTITY % mathent SYSTEM "math.ent"> %mathent; ]>

<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook MathML Module V1.1b1//EN"
          "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/mathml/1.1CR1/dbmathml.dtd">
```

This is a very common question on stackoverflow and elsewhere, but none of the answers are actually able to deal with both cases.

My naive approach of `<!DOCTYPE((.|\n|\r)*?)(\"|])>` will correctly match the second case, but fail on the first one (it stops at the first `">` and leaves `%mathen; ]>` unmatched.) If I try to make the regex more greedy, it tries to consume the whole document instead.

Complete test cases:

- [first](https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/ecosystem/public/sdk/docs/man2/glClear.xml)
- [second](https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/ogl/trunk/ecosystem/public/sdk/docs/man4/glClear.xml)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

EDIT: Fixed the comment match, thanks TheFiddler

Well, you could use something like (the not entirely beautiful);

```
<!DOCTYPE[^>[]*(\[[^]]*\])?>
```

It matches a `<!` and everything up to a `>` or `[`, followed by an optional section surrounded by `[]`, followed by a final `>`.

[A JSfiddle to test with](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%3C!DOCTYPE%5B%5E%3E%5B%5D%2a%28%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5D%2a%5C%5D%29%3F%3E&input=%3C!DOCTYPE%20refentry%20%5B%20%3C!ENTITY%20%25%20mathent%20SYSTEM%20%22math.ent%22%3E%20%25mathent%3B%20%5D%3Ejfkdjksdfj%5D%3E%0A%0A%3C!DOCTYPE%20book%20PUBLIC%20%22-%2F%2FOASIS%2F%2FDTD%20DocBook%20MathML%20Module%20V1.1b1%2F%2FEN%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oasis-open.org%2Fdocbook%2Fxml%2Fmathml%2F1.1CR1%2Fdbmathml.dtd%22%3Ejkdjsfdkfd%0A).

More detail;

```
<!DOCTYPE     -- matches the string <!DOCTYPE
[^>[]*        -- matches anything up to a > or [
(\[[^]]*\])?  -- matches an optional section surrounded by []
>             -- matches the string >
```

Comment: If the document has ] and > in order anywhere else in it, your greedy match will match far too much. Plus, even when it works, the greedy match will have to backtrack. Better to use a lazy match.

Comment: This will also match <!-- --> comments within the document (check the xml test files in my question.) However, a small change to `<!DOCTYPE[^>[]*(\[[^]]*\])?>` appears to work as expected, so unless someone has a better answer I will accept this :)

Comment: @TheFiddler Ah, yes, missed that. Updated the answer.

Comment: @TheFiddler for what it's worth, you don't have to escape closing square bracket ].

Answer (score 1):

I suggest below RegEx,

```
 <!DOCTYPE.*(\[[\s\S]*?\])?>
```

[Try this link](https://regexr.com/5hi7g)